# ¿Como establecer una sentencia para que no devuelve valores NULL teniendo dos condiciones en PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

Poseo el siguiente código para consultar a la base de datos:

```
<?php
include_once '__conexion.php';
require "funciones/JSON.php";
?>
<?php
  $cedula = 111111; //No existe
  $estado=1; 
   //-- Obtener Ultimo ID de sancion registrado para ese sancionado --//
  $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT max(id_omd) FROM sanciones WHERE cedula_sancionado = ? AND estado_sancion_id = ?");
  var_dump($stmt)."<br>";
  $stmt->bind_param("ii", $cedula, $estado);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  $cantidad=$stmt->num_rows;
  var_dump($cantidad);
  $stmt->bind_result($ultimoregistro);
  $stmt->fetch();

  if ($stmt->num_rows === 0) {
  echo "No registro";
  } else {
  echo "Si hay registros";
  }
```

**El problema**: En la base de datos NO hay ningún registro con esos datos Haciendo la consulta en phpMyAdmin se obtiene un valor NULL:

```
max(id_omd)
NULL
```

Cuando uso `var_dump($canrtidad)`; me devuelve `int(0)`.

Pero sigue pasando la consulta como que si hay registros, invalidando `$stmt->num_rows===0`

Comment: El error 500, se produce generalmente por un problema de permiso. si mal no recuerdo en los **hosting** los permisos deben de estar en 0755. Tienda ha suceder que cuando lo creamos local y lo subimos al servidor se cambie los permisos.

Comment: @YoelRodriguez publique por error esta pregunta, culpa de mi internet, no es asi, la duda.

Comment: me parece que el problema es ===... no son del mismo tipo, o no lo serian.. depende como compile.. probaste con ==?

Comment: El problema es que contar el número de filas no es el mejor parámetro para saber si hay registros. De hecho, tu ejemplo lo demuestra, ya que lo que hace es contar cuántas filas hay, y de hecho, hay una fila, sólo que el valor en la misma es `NULL` de ahí que una forma más eficaz de evaluar nuestros datos es preguntando por los mismos datos. O sea, almacernar los datos obtenidos y preguntando si la variable donde los estás almacenando es `NULL`o no: `if ($datos){... hay datos ...}else{ ... no hay datos ... }`

Comment: @A.Cedano $ultimoregistro > 0 , Funciono, publica tu respuesta :), lo utilice de esa forma porque en otras consultas no me generaba ese dato NULO, porque lo hace?, acaso hay un valor en MYSQL esperando un dato?, como ocurre en los numeros binarios?. NOTA lo mas comico es que num_rows me sigue devolviendo INT(0) cuando hay registros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El uso de `num_rows` para saber si hay **datos reales** en un conjunto de resultados no es mucho de fiar, aunque sea la práctica más habitual en muchas respuestas, por desgracia...

Este caso es típico de ello, pues se pregunta por el número de filas que hay y, en efecto, hay una fila, sólo que los datos en ella son **nulos**.

> Haciendo la consulta en phpMyAdmin se obtiene un valor NULL:

```
max(id_omd)
NULL
```

**No hay datos**, o más bien,  **hay una fila sin datos o con datos nulos**.

Entonces, lo más seguro es preguntar por los datos mismos.

Si tienes datos almacenados aquí:

```
  $stmt->bind_result($ultimoregistro);
```

**pregunta por ellos**:

He cambiado el orden, pero puedes preguntar también en negativo...

```
  if ($ultimoregistro) {
  echo "Si hay registros";
  } else {
  echo "No registro";
  }
```

La cosa quedaría más o menos así:

```
  $cedula = 111111; //No existe
  $estado=1; 
   //-- Obtener Ultimo ID de sancion registrado para ese sancionado --//
  $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT max(id_omd) FROM sanciones WHERE cedula_sancionado = ? AND estado_sancion_id = ?");
  var_dump($stmt)."<br>";
  $stmt->bind_param("ii", $cedula, $estado);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  $cantidad=$stmt->num_rows;
  var_dump($cantidad);
  $stmt->bind_result($ultimoregistro);
  $stmt->fetch();

  if ($ultimoregistro) {
  echo "Si hay registros";
  } else {
  echo "No registro";
  }
```

**Nota**

El que devuelva `NULL` es otra cosa, puede deberse a un error en los datos o en la consulta SQL o en el que simplemente el campo del `SELECT` que cumple la condición no tiene datos y es una columna que acepta nulos.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrias que checar que tipo de valor te devuelve `num_rows` ya que si te esta devolviendo '0' como `String` y tu lo comparas con 0 como `int` no se cumple la condicion al usar `===` ya que así estas diciendo que ademas de tener el mismo valor, deben de ser del mismo tipo, en cambio si utilizas `==` solo verifica que tengan el mismo valor sin importar el tipo de cada uno de ellos.

Comment: Me esta regresando INT(0) -> $var_ump($cantidad = $stmt->num_rows)

Answer (score 1):

Existe otra solución posible:

`if (!empty($stmt->num_rows)) { // OJO con el ! para cambiar el resultado de empty
    echo "Si hay registros ";
  } else {
    echo "No registro";
  }`

De esa forma puedes validar un 0 o un NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la comprobación de esta forma:

> Una solución

```
  if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
    echo " No registro";
  } else {
    echo "Si hay registros";
  }
```

> Otra solución

```
  if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "Si hay registros ";
  } else {
    echo "No registro";
  }
```

Comment: Te edito la respuesta para que pruebes.

Comment: Ya modifique la pregunta, probe y me arroja int(0), tendre que voltear el IF

Comment: te la modifique si quieres de la otra forma la puedes hacer igual